# Logout using MGTwitterEngine?

Tags: iphone

How to logout using MGTwitterEngine API programmatically in iphone ?

Answer (score 3):

You mean how do you log out from the current account in MGTwitterEngine?

Well, that's easy, simply send the `-endUserSession`-selector to the engine like this:

```
MGTwitterEngine *engine = [MGTwitterEngine twitterEngineWithDelegate:self];
// Login...
// Do stuff...
[engine endUserSession]; // <-- Logs out
```

Comment: Now, whenever I use this function, it's alway a HTTP error code 400

Comment: Now, whenever I use this function, it's alway return a HTTP error. It take a look inside the method endUserSession. If the path is "account/end_session", the error code is 401. Then if I change the path as "account/end_session.[json/xml]", the error code is 400

Answer (score 2):

To Logout of the Twitter from MGTwitterEngine you need to call its methods with some change. In the MGTwitterEngine.m, search for `_clearCookies`. This is currently set to NO, change it to YES. In your action method for logging out the current user, call `[ _engine clearAccessToken]`.

Now run it, and voila, it works!